# Where can I find SysLog output?

Tags: java, windows, syslog

I have no prior experience with Java and I'm trying to debug a Java class. The class gets called from C++ code. The Java code is full of `SysLog` calls that would be very helpful to me, but I can't figure out where the output goes, if anywhere.

`SysLog` is initialized quite simply like this:

```
public static void initLogger() {
    if (log == null) {
        log = new Syslog();
    }
}
```

And just to complicate matters, this code is running as a Windows service which means it cannot display any sort of UI, not even console output. The logging must go to a file to be useful.

Do I need to do something to enable the logging? If so, what?

Do I need to do something to send the logging to file(s)? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

Some info about Syslog - it was originally developed as a generic UNIX logging service.  It can log local messages from the system or collect log messages from a number of different servers on the network.  Generally any UNIX system will have some implementation of a syslog service available on it.  It is a common way of aggregating messages from a number of systems.

On windows, there are a number of syslog server implementations out there.  If a syslog service is running on your windows box, then the message might be ending up there.

However, the real question is: to which syslog services does your java app send messages?  In theory you could configure your java app to send syslog messages to a remote machine.  Or it could try to send messages to the local host (since the syslog listens on a default port).

So I think what VD is saying is to check your java application settings and look for syslog configuration settings.  You will have to gain access to a syslog server (either install one locally on windows or get a remote machine to listen).  And then using this [link](https://blog.trifork.com/2010/01/14/logging-to-the-syslog-from-a-java-application/) configure your java app appropriately.

An additional complication might be that your java environment uses a custom or special sysloghandler.  The log4j is very common and is probably the default, but you might want to check that as well.

Comment: It is log4j. Thanks for the info but I'll pursue it elsewhere.